# How to use jinja if-else logic together with Ansible inventory

Tags: templates, ansible, yaml, jinja2, aws-cloudformation

I would like to use jinja logic in my template:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: '{{ git_repository.after | truncate(8, end='') }} @ infra-lambda.git : roles/{{ lambda_name }}'

Resources:

{% if lambda_account == 'true' %}
  RoleToAssume:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: "infra-lambda-{{ lambda_name }}-LambdaRole-{{ shortname }}-{{ dtap }}"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: RoleToAssumeLambdaPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "cloudwatch:Get*"
                  - "cloudwatch:List*"
                  - "cloudwatch:Put*"
                Resource:
                  - "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "sts:AssumeRole"
                Resource:
                  - "*"

{% else %}
  RoleToBeAssumed:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: RoleToBeAssumed
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: DefaultStatement
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - "arn:aws:iam::{AWS_ACCOUNT}:role/lambda_assume"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "DeleteCertificates"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - acm:DeleteCertificate
                  - acm:GetCertificate
                Action:
                  - acm:ListCertificates
                Resource: '*'
{% endif %}
```

I've already tried true without '' and instead of true is defined but still no success. The logic is pretty simple. In the inventory I have:

```
unused_certs:
  enabled: true
  lambda_account: true
```

If I have the above in the inventory only RoleToAssume and LambdaFunction resources should be created. If I don’t have lambda_account set to true, only the resources after the else statement should be created. Any idea why only the resources after the else statement are being created by CloudFormation? I cannot use "when" in Ansible playbook because my repo is not constructed that way unfortunately.

Comment: How are you passing `unused_certs` to the template?

Comment: What is the error you're having or what is the behavior you get and how does it differ from the one you expect? Please see [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section.

Answer (score 1):

The "pythonic" way to write the sentence is just:

```
{% if lambda_account %}
```

But you can still use true with lowercase, as stated in the [jinja2 docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if).

```
{% if lambda_account == true %}
```

Comment: In an Ansible context, the secure way is `{% if lambda_account | bool %}`

Comment: Thanks! The first answer worked for me! I was sure I've tested this before (maybe I did other changes to the code and that's why I excluded this option from further testings)